# I cant Change Logo Color & Menu Underline / Links Not Working

Tags: html, css, sass, menu

Hello this is my first time using Sass on a project so im not sure if it is because I setup the code in correctly in sass or if its the particles js causing issues.

1. Logo -  For some reason im able to change the size of the logo but I'm not able to change the color.
2. Menu Links - Not sure why but for some reason the menu's underline is not working and I cant even click on them if I wanted to but when I change the size of links it works.

Here is a link in case you want see it live
http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

```
<div id="header-home">
   
   <!-- <div id="particles-js"></div> -->
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <img src="img/RE-LOGO_01.png" alt="My Portfolio Logo" id="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>


        </nav>
        <div class="header-content">
            <h1>DESIGNER</h1>
            <h1>+</h1>
            <h1>DEVELOPER</h1>
            <p class="lead">Welcome to my website. I am a Graphic / Web Designer & Web Developer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
    #logo {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    
    
    #main-nav {
        z-index: 20;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        background: none;

   

     ul {
            display: flex;
        }
        
        li {
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    
        }
    
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            // CSS Below is For Border Bottom Hover Effect
            border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            transition: border-color 1s;
    
            &:hover {
                border-color: $light-blue;
            }
            
            &.current {
                border-color: $yellow-color;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with the logo is with your normal CSS rules - you can't change the colour of an image using `color` - that property is for text. For your menu links, have you defined the variables you are using for the `border-color`?

Comment: Thanks but the logo is just an png image.

Comment: As I said, `color` only works on text. Your logo is a png *image*, which means `color` won't have any effect on it because it's not *text*. Your SASS looks fine. I think you should try to get the rules working in standard CSS first so you can rule out and SASS problems, and identify where the issue is. Then when you have the standard CSS working, change them to SASS.

Comment: That’s a good idea I will definitely try that. And thanks for telling me about png files I did not know that.

Comment: First rule of debugging - go back and start simple, then add the code back but by bit until you get the error again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problems. By playing with the code and getting some advice on here.

1. for the logo I just uploaded a white svg to save time. At first I was try to upload svg at original colro and change it with css but after looking at examples it looked like you need to add a lot of code or use some javascript so to make it easy I just changed the color in photoshop.
2. to fix the navbar I add position Relative in css

HTML

```
<nav id="main-nav">
                    <img src="img/logo-white-1.svg" alt="My Portfolio Logo" id="logo">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" class="current">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </nav>
```

SASS

```
#main-nav {
    z-index: 20;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    background: none;
    position: relative;


    ul {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    li {
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;

    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        // CSS Below is For Border Bottom Hover Effect
        border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
        transition: border-color 1s;

        &:hover {
            border-color: $light-blue;
        }
        
        &.current {
            border-color: $yellow-color;
        }

    }

}
```

I uploaded to this domain for now but I plan on moving the website to another domain later (in case this link doesnt work in the future)

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

Answer (score 0):

The div's with classes `.particles-js-canvas-el, .header-content, #header-home #particles-js, #header-home` are above the nav bar which are making to click on those items instead of actual nav bar elements, so you have to send them back and get the navbar to front so that you can click on the items.

Add the follwing code at the end of the main.css file

**css/main.css**

```
.white-logo { filter: brightness(100); }

body
{
    background: #00111e;
}
.particles-js-canvas-el, .header-content, #header-home #particles-js
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#header-home
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

To change color of the logo, apply the required class from the css

```
<img src="img/RE-LOGO_01.png" alt="My Portfolio Logo" id="logo" class="white-logo">
```

Thank you

Comment: The other div's are covering the nav bar above, so I made some adjstments in the code, so that nav links worked and the underline below the link also works.
I will try to change the logo to white, sorry for that.

Comment: If this code fixes the problem, then please explain *how* it does. Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not help users understand what to do to fix the problem. Also make note that you are using code that wasn't provided in the question, because your answer doesn't make sense in context of the question. Please browse the [help for answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) to see how to answer questions so they are helpful.

Comment: Thanks I tried the code above and did not work.  Im using Sass so maybe it has something to do with that. also where did you find particles-js-canvas-el from? I didnt have this class in my code.

Comment: It is present in the link that you have provided. Maybe that is created by the particlejs script.